# Pulling Google Apps user creation date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

What options are there to pull a GApps user creation date?
I saw that the Admin SDK is capable of it, is it the only API capable of doing this? does any of the previous one also capable of?
If possible using GAS, it will be most excellent,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there does not seem be Google Apps Script services to pull the creation date.  The [DomainUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/domain-user) class provide interesting functionality for interacting with domain users (only for admins).

Using the Admin SDK with Google Apps Script using [UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) is not as complex as it looks.  You can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795332/whar-is-the-oauth-service-name-for-the-google-apps-reseller-api/18798275#18798275) which will throw some light on how you can use external API calls for certain Google API and bring the data to Google Apps Script.

The scope for the ADMIN SDK will be as follows

```
oAuthConfig1.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken
?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
```

Notice that in this case I have requested a readonly scope.